# MERGE and ON DELETE CASCADE in Oracle XE 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-xe

**In short** (tl;dr): When trying to delete rows during a `MERGE`, Oracle 10g seems to ignore `ON DELETE CASCADE` statements for foreign keys. I would like to know if this is a known bug, a feature (apparently discontinued in 11g), or what.

More in detail:
It seems to me that in Oracle XE 10g, trying to delete rows from a table within a `MERGE` statement leads to an ORA-02292 error (violation of referential integrity) *whenever* there is a foreign key referencing the destination table of the merge, even if `ON DELETE CASCADE` was specified in the foreign key constraint.
For example, say I create three tables

```
CREATE TABLE Mysource(
  MykeyS NUMBER,
  MystringS VARCHAR2(10),
  CONSTRAINT Mysource_PK PRIMARY KEY(MykeyS) ENABLE
);

CREATE TABLE Mydest(
  MykeyD NUMBER,
  MystringD VARCHAR2(10),
  CONSTRAINT Mydest_PK PRIMARY KEY(MykeyD) ENABLE
);

CREATE TABLE Myother(
  Mykey NUMBER,
  Mydate DATE,
  CONSTRAINT Myother_FK FOREIGN KEY(Mykey)
  REFERENCES Mydest(MykeyD) ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE
);
```

and insert some data in them, then try

```
MERGE INTO Mydest D
USING Mysource S
ON (D.MykeyD=S.MykeyS)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET D.MystringD = S.MystringS
DELETE WHERE (S.MykeyS > 10)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (MykeyD, MystringD)
VALUES (S.MykeyS, S.MystringS)
WHERE (S.MykeyS <= 10)
```

If both `Mydest` and `Myother` had some rows with >10 key, the attempted MERGE would then result in an ORA-02292, claiming a violation of the `Myother_FK` constraint.
This sounds illogical to me (I can delete rows from `Mydest` using a direct `DELETE`, but not with a `MERGE`?), and in fact it does not seem to happen with Oracle XE 11g.

**Question:**
Do you know if this is a known bug, or a weird feature? Or am I missing something, maybe? Searching the internet has not helped much, so far.

Comment: Good catch. I think it is a bug in 10g. Reproduced with my own test case on Oracle 10.2.0.4. Verified working on 11.2.0.1.

Comment: Oracle has it listed as bug 8268746 in 10.2.0.3, fixed in 11.2. The work-around is not to use merge :)

Comment: C'mon, @Glenn, put that as an answer!

Comment: thanks @Glenn, I think you should write that as an answer.

Comment: @AdamHawkes Thanks guys, answer posted. But in reality that was a better question than answer. As Jeffrey said, good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle has it listed as bug 8268746 in 10.2.0.3. It is fixed in 11.2. The document is not available for linking externally, but it provides a test case similar to the example provided in the question above. The work-around is to not use the merge statement (or upgrade to 11.2).

Comment: Thanks again! Does _not available for linking externally_ mean there is no "official" and verifiable source for this?

Comment: @fudo If you have a support contract, you can log into metalink.oracle.com and search their bug database. Put in the bug number and you will find it. But you will need a login to access the page.

Comment: uh… I do have an Oracle login (I had to create it in order to download Oracle XE 11g), but I don't think I have a _support contract_. Thanks anyway :)